# PHP Directory listening

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to do at the moment a small Filebrowser in php

With this part of code i show up my Files on Page load.

```
$dir = './files';
$directories = array();
$files_list  = array();
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
   if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..')){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
         $directories[]  = $file;

      }else{
         $files_list[]    = $file;

      }
   }
}

foreach($directories as $directory){
                    ?>
                     <div class="a_folder" id="<?php echo "$here/files/$directory" ?>">
                     <div class="a_file_icon"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_name"><?php echo $directory ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_size"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_last"><?php echo date ("Y-m-d  H:i:s.", filemtime('./files/' . $directory)) ?></div>
                     </div>
                    <?php
}
foreach($files_list as $file_list){
                    ?>
                     <div class="a_file">
                     <div class="a_file_icon_file"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_name"><?php echo $file_list ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_size"><?php echo FileSizeConvert(filesize('./files/' . $file_list)); ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_last"><?php echo date ("Y-m-d  H:i:s.", filemtime('./files/' . $file_list)) ?></div>
                     </div>
                    <?php
}
```

Then i have when it is a Folder a small Ajax request over JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".a_folder").click(function()
    {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");

                     $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"./ajax/getFiles.php",
                data:{ 'ID': ID},
                success: function(data){
                    $(".content").html(data)
                    }
                }); 


    });
});
```

The getFiles.php

```
$filename= $_POST["ID"];
$dir = $filename;
$directories = array();
$files_list  = array();
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
   if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..')){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
         $directories[]  = $file;

      }else{
         $files_list[]    = $file;

      }
   }
}

foreach($directories as $directory){
                    ?>
                     <div class="a_folder" id="<?php echo $directory ?>">
                     <div class="a_file_icon"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_name"><?php echo $directory ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_size"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_last"><?php echo date ("Y-m-d  H:i:s.", filemtime('./files/' . $directory)) ?></div>
                     </div>
                    <?php
}
foreach($files_list as $file_list){
                    ?>
                     <div class="a_file">
                     <div class="a_file_icon_file"></div>
                     <div class="a_file_name"><?php echo $file_list ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_size"><?php echo FileSizeConvert(filesize('./files/' . $file_list)); ?></div>
                     <div class="a_file_last"><?php echo date ("Y-m-d  H:i:s.", filemtime('./files/' . $file_list)) ?></div>
                     </div>
                    <?php
}
```

So but actually I have trouble with my path handling. 
How can i make sure that the script gets everytime the correct path ?

Feel free to ask when there is some open Questions

Comment: What is it - `right path`?

Comment: Excuse , correct Path

Comment: What is correct path?

Comment: Question remains the same - which path is correct/right/etc and which is not?

Answer (score 0):

The id for the first is set like this:

```
<div class="a_folder" id="<?php echo "$here/files/$directory" ?>">
```

I can see no `$here` in the rest of the code.

First page uses `$dir = './files';`

**The getFiles.php**

Is using:

```
$filename= $_POST["ID"];
$dir = $filename;
```

Your `$_POST["ID"]` is going to look like `/files/$directory`

So you are missing the `./`

My suggestion would be to change:

```
$directories[]  = $file;
```

To this:

```
$directories[]  = $dir.'/'.$file;
```

And alter this:

```
<div class="a_folder" id="<?php echo "$directory" ?>">
```

Also look at using absoulte paths, and this is not very secure!